# How to download/save file to blob starage via azure app functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm new to Azure. I need http triggered function to perform some simple actions on my blob storage. This will be the part of pipeline in datafactory but first I need to figure it out how to edit blobs via functions. I'm stucked now because I have no idea which API/methods I could use. Appreciate for your help. Below is some part of my code.

```
def main(req):
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        requested_file = requests.get("web address")
        ### Should I connect to blob here?
        with open("file.txt", "wb") as file:
            file.write(requested_file.content)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776039/read-data-from-azure-blob-storage-in-azure-function-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read data from Azure blob storage in Azure Function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776039/read-data-from-azure-blob-storage-in-azure-function-in-python)

Comment: @Thomas Partialy yes. But how Can I do reverse - Download file and save it to blob?

Comment: download file from where ?

Comment: @Thomas Download file from internet (for example some .csv or txt files) via requests library. Then save this on blob.

Comment: It's not clear specifically what issue you're having, but... Azure Functions have no issue writing to blob storage. As for editing blobs, you cannot edit a blob in-place (unless it's a page blob, which doesn't really fit the scenario here). You'd need to download to working storage (or memory) within your function app, manipulate your data as needed, then upload to a blob. Same with an existing blob - download to local storage, edit, then upload to blob.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the [Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-overview)

Or use [bindings and triggers for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python)

How you would do it is use the bindings to pull in your blob and then use the bindings to write out your blob. This is actually a pretty [good example of it:](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/v2functions/queue-trigger-blob-in-out-binding/__init__.py)

Similarly with the SDK, you want to make sure that you are calling in and writing out. Make sure all your keys are correct and your containers are too!