# Python Azure function triggered by Blob storage printing file name incorrectly

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm triggering an Azure function with a blob trigger event.
A container ***sample-workitems*** has a file ***base.csv*** and receives a new file ***new.csv***. I'm reading ***base.csv*** from the ***sample-workitems*** and ***new.csv*** from InputStream for the same container.

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream, base: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    logging.info(f"Base file info \n"
                 f"Name: {base.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {base.length} bytes")
                 
    df_base = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(base.read()))
    df_new = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(myblob.read()))
    print(df_new.head())
    print("prnting base dataframe")
    print(df_base.head())
```

**Output:**

```
Python blob trigger function processed blob 
Name: samples-workitems/new.csv
Blob Size: None bytes
Base file info 
Name: samples-workitems/new.csv
Blob Size: None bytes
first 5 rows of df_new (cannot show data here)
prnting base dataframe
first 5 rows of df_base (cannot show data here)
```

Even though both files show their own content when printing but `myblob.name` and `base.name` has the same value ***new.csv*** which is unexpected. `myblob.name` would have ***new.csv*** while `base.name` would have ***base.csv***

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{name}",
      "connection": "my_storage"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "base",
      "path": "samples-workitems/base.csv",
      "connection": "my_storage",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and the below code worked for me and I followed code of @SwethaKandikonda 's [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570504/read-files-from-azure-blob-storage-using-python-azure-functions)

****init**.py:**

```
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
    file="" 
    fileContent=""       
    blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name="rithwikstor",account_key="EJ7xCyq2+AStqiar7Q==")
    containername="samples-workitems"
    generator = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name=containername) 
    for blob in generator:
        file=blob_service.get_blob_to_text(containername,blob.name)
        logging.info(blob.name)
        logging.info(file.content)
        fileContent+=blob.name+'\n'+file.content+'\n\n'
```

**function.json:**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{name}",
      "connection": "rithwikstor_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "Connection String Of storage account",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "rithwikstor_STORAGE": "Connection String Of storage account"
  }
}
```

**Host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  }
}
```

**Then i added blobs as below:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

Please try to file the above process and code, you will get correct output as I have got.