# Reading NLP models from Azure blob container

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, sentence-transformers, azure-python-sdk

I have uploaded the sentence transformer model on my blob container. The idea is to load the model into a Python notebook from the blob container. To do this I do the following:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
service = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://<name_of_my_blob>.blob.core.windows.net/", credential=credential)
```

then point to the location on the container where my model is i.e.:
`https://<name_of_my_blob>.blob.core.windows.net/fla-models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2`,

```
model = SentenceTransformer(service.get_blob_to_path('fla-models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2'))
```

But I get

```
AttributeError: 'BlobServiceClient' object has no attribute 'get_blob_to_path'
```

I have the latest installation of `azure-storage-blob`. I wonder what am I doing wrong there and if the Azure lib is not longer supporting `get_blob_to_path` method?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

> 'BlobServiceClient' object has no attribute 'get_blob_to_path'

The above error tells that **`BlobServiceClient`** is not longer supporting `get_blob_to_path` method. because **`Blockblobservice`** is the library is using `get_blob_to_path`.

Example:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')

block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('mycontainer', 'myblockblob', 'filename')
```

if you need read the file in azure blob storage you can use the below code:

**Code:**

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient
import json
service=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<connection_string>")

container_client = service.get_container_client("test")
model=service.get_blob_client( "test",blob="all-MiniLM-L6-v2/modules.json"))
blob_data = model.download_blob()
data = json.loads(blob_data.readall())
print(data)
```

**Console:**

In portal **`all-MiniLM-L6-v2`**is blob name(folder), If you run only blob folder name it won't run you need use specific file name inside the folder.

[image]

If you need **`all-MiniLM-L6-v2`** to get what are the files are present you can use the below code:

**Code:**

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

service=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<connection_string>")

container_client = service.get_container_client("test")
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()

for  blob  in  blob_list:\

print("\t" + blob.name)
```

**Console:**
[image]

For your reference you can use this [So-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570504/read-files-from-azure-blob-storage-using-python-azure-functions) works with function.